# Creating URL with formula in excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink

In my excel sheet I am creating URLs by concatenating the content of various cells.

The formula in D2 is `=CONCATENATE("http://",A2,".",B2)`

[image]

The problem I have is that the resulting URL is not seen as a hyperlink, and I have to manually copy, paste as value and then configure the hyperlink to make it work.

Is there a way to let excel recognize it as a URL and make it immediatly clickable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **D2** enter:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://",A2,".",B2),CONCATENATE("http://",A2,".",B2))
```

*(you can now replace the second argument with a "user friendly" label)*